# How to Retrieve A/D User Information for a user

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to reproduce some of the functionality of the app 'Active Directory Users and Computers", and am not finding an easy way to retrieve the A/D information for a given user, using the account name, or "samaccountname".

Currently, I create a DirectoryEntry using the domain user and password, then use the entry to instantiate a DirectorySearcher to perform a FindAll().  I then run through the resulting SearchResultCollection's SearchResults, resolving UserPrincipals and their various properties to assemble all the A/D users in the OU.  This takes way too long.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(
    LDAPString, domainuserid, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
SearchResultCollection results = srch.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult sr in results)
{
    DirectoryEntry de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
    if (de.Name.IndexOf("CN=") > -1)
    {
        foreach (string propKey in sr.Properties.PropertyNames)
        {
            user = new ADUser();
            UserPrincipal up = GetServiceUser(sr.Properties["samaccountname"][0].ToString());
            user.AccountName = up.SamAccountName;
            user.Name = up.Name;
            foreach (string propKey in sr.Properties.PropertyNames)
            {
                switch (propKey.Trim().ToLower())
                {
                    case "givenname":
                        user.SurName = sr.Properties[propKey][0].ToString();
                        break;
                    ETC...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've done timings and this part of the process seems to take way more time than it should.  It occurs to me that I might retrieve all the SamAccountNames of A/D users, display them in a list, and only when selected to retrieve all the relevant data for that user.  I've not run into a way to do this retrieval one at a time, as-needed, and it seems that would be more efficient.  Is there a programmatic way to get an A/D user's information solely by use of the SamAccountName?

**Edited to Add:**

I thought I had found an answer to this, but then found it to be not quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I wrote a little AD tool, I used `FindOne` to retrieve and modify detail data via the SamAccountName. I don't know exactly how performant it was compared to your solution (it really was some time ago), but it worked pretty well by then (also with plenty of items):

```
// get the user entry
var s = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
s.Filter = "(samaccountname=" + username + ")";
SearchResult user = s.FindOne();

// read / do some changes
var d = user.GetDirectoryEntry();
d.Properties[...]
d.Invoke(...);
d.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make use of the `srch.Filter` to refine your LDAP query:

```
DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);  // You already have this line

srch.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", samAccountName);
```

Now you can actually just use `srch.FindOne()` instead of `srch.FindAll()` since samaccountname is unique.